# Count amount of arrays in a database

Tags: javascript, sql, discord.js, better-sqlite3

I have a database and I will lay out an example.

```js
guildid    botid
1234       ["2345","3456","3714","1812"]
9876       ["8765","5432"]
4346       NULL
2371       ["3179"]
1254       NULL
1257       ["1721","7104","8265"]
8321       NULL
```

I need to output the amount of botids there are, in this example the answer = `10`.
There are 7 records in the db, but 10 total ids that are not NULL
Normally I would do `SELECT count(*) FROM watchedbots` However this only counts how many records there are. On some occasions, the botid can also be `NULL` so I need it to ignore the NULL entries. I am fairly new when it comes to arrays so any help would be appreciated.
The module I use for SQL is `better-sqlite3`

Edit: expanded the example

If I do the following:

```js
const dataGrab = db.prepare('SELECT botid FROM watchedbots').all()
const stringify = JSON.stringify(dataGrab)
console.log(stringify)
```

I get an output of:
`[{"botid":null},{"botid":null},{"botid":null},{"botid":"["1721","7104","8265"]"},{"botid":"["2345","3456","3714","1812"]"},{"botid":"["3179"]"},{"botid":"["8765","5432"]"}]`
Which I am guessing is a good next step, not sure where I would go from there though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your simplest method is to iterate over the base array.

```
let count = 0;
for(guild of dataGrab) {
    if(guild.botid) {
        let arr = guild.botid.slice(1, guild.botid.length -1).split(',');
        count += arr.length;
    }
}
console.log(count);
```

Comment: This is outputting 74

Comment: Hmm, looking at your results, it looks like array may be returned as a string rather than an array object.  So it may be counting the string characters.  We may have to do some string manipulation.  Let me edit.

Comment: Technically you don't have to do the slice because all you are doing is counting and the split would end the same anyway.  But I included it in case you needed to access the individual numbers as an array, it removes the [ and ].